# informatica convertion issue from timestamp to date (DD-MON-YY)

Tags: informatica-powercenter

I have one issue while converting  from `TIMESTAMP(17-SEP-15 02.00.00.000000 PM)` format to `DATE(DD-MON-YY)` format in a informatica Mapping.

It works fine when I use the ODBC driver connection.  But when we use  ORACLE data direct connection it gives the ERROR.

Are there any solutions?

Comment: Where are ypu getting the issue, in source qualifier? What is the error message?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  I have fixed English issues with your post.  Please edit the post and tell us what error you are getting.

Answer (score 0):

Try using DATE(DD-MON-RR), I think this should work.